# Is there a free beginner house in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for a beginner house to store unique items and other stuff, at level 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anise's Cabin fits the bill. The house is Southwest of Riverwood, across White River, 
South of Bleak Falls Barrow.

The house contains a bed, an arcane enchanter and alchemy lab as well as several containers.

The Cabin is owned by Anise, but if you go into the cellar inside the cabin, and then exit, she will attack you. You can then kill her and claim the cabin. The bed becomes un-owned, but everything else is still owned, so either fence the items, or drop them somewhere.

EDIT: Jim reminded me about the containers. The containers in the basement do not reset. Most of the ones above ground are also safe, but the barrel is not. To be safe, only store stuff in the basement.

Comment: Well, do the containers reset?

Comment: @Jim. no. your name should be longer so i don't have to type so much.

Comment: @ton.yeung what are you talking about? If my name is short, then you would type a little right? If it's Jim Anderson [Not really my last name, Anderson], then you typed to much.

Comment: never mind. it was a joke that didn't really come across. And the containers in the basement do not reset. Most of the ones above ground are also safe, but the barrel is not. To be safe only store stuff in the basement.

Comment: @ton.yeung Oh I get it why you need to say that joke, it was because when commenting, you need to have more than like 10 characters before you can submit the comment.